# Reduce higher order function in Swift 3.0 with Int enum

Tags: swift, swift3

I am learning Swift higher order functions associated with Collections. I have following query with `reduce`

```
enum Coin : Int {
    case Penny = 1
    case Nickel = 5
    case Dime = 10
    case Quarter = 25
}

let coinArray: [Coin] = [.Dime, .Quarter, .Penny, .Penny, .Nickel, .Nickel]

coinArray.reduce(0,{ (x:Coin, y:Coin) -> Int in
    return x.rawValue + y.rawValue
})
```

I am getting following error:

> Declared closure result Int is incompatible with contextual type _

Comment: If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see how `reduce` is declared:

```
public func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

See the type of `nextPartialResult`? It is `(Result, Element) -> Result`. What is the type of `Result`, in your case? It is `Int`, because you want to reduce the whole thing to an integer.

Therefore, passing a `(Coin, Coin) -> Int` does not really work here, does it?

You should pass in a `(Int, Coin) -> Int` instead.

```
coinArray.reduce(0,{ (x:Int, y:Coin) -> Int in
    return x + y.rawValue
})
```

Or simply:

```
coinArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.rawValue }
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you apply `reduce` onto the `coinArray` you get the following signature:

[image]

Ask yourself what is the type of the *generic* Result? Is it of type `coin` or of type `Int`? What is the type of `nextPartialResult`? Is it of type `coin` or of type `Int`?

The answer is: `Result` is an `Int` and and `nextPartialResult` is a *closure* 'that takes one parameter of type result which here is `Int` and another parameter of type `coin` and eventually returns an `Int`'

So the correct way of writing it is:

```
coinArray.reduce(0,{ (x, y) -> Int in
    return x + y.rawValue
})
```

Or in a more meaningful sense you could have wrote:

```
coinArray.reduce(0,{ (currentResult, coin) -> Int in
    return currentResult + coin.rawValue
})
```

also `coinArray` isn't a good name. Just write `coins`. It being plural makes is more readable than `coinArray` / `arrayOfCoins`!

Comment: `also coinArray isn't a good name. Just write coins. It being plural makes is more readable than coinArray / arrayOfCoins!` I wonder where you picked that up from 

Comment: @Alexander looking into Erica Sadun's [book](http://ericasadun.com/2016/12/14/buy-a-book-swift-style/) and also validating it from Apple's Swift guide. You will rarely see the names similar to coinArray or arrayOfCoins.